# How to use or escape the at symbol @ so it can be used in R package documentation?

Tags: r, r-package, roxygen2, roxygen

`@` is a special character in R documentation, so how can we use the literal `@` in the documentation?

I have tried using single, double, triple and quadrupal backslashes. But no luck.

#### Example

```
#' @importFrom utils file.edit
#'
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' library(dplyr)
#' medium("https://medium.com/@data_datum/ggplot2-or-how-to-make-fancy-graphics-with-r-fabae7fc16d4")
#'
```

In the above example, the `@` in the url will cause a syntax error

Answer (score 2):

Double the `@` symbol. I.e. replace `@` with `@@`

i.e. change

```
#' medium("https://medium.com/@data_datum/ggplot2-or-how-to-make-fancy-graphics-with-r-fabae7fc16d4")
```

to

```
#' medium("https://medium.com/@@data_datum/ggplot2-or-how-to-make-fancy-graphics-with-r-fabae7fc16d4")
```

See another example [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/formatting.html)